# What does it mean even? And odd?

Tags: terminology

I'm actually an international student and I'm not very confident with specific mathematical terms. I was doing some exercises when I came up to the words *even* and *odd*. What do they mean exactly?

Here's the context:

> Which of the following relations are ***even***?
>
> I. something
>   II. something 
>   III. something
>
> **Results:**
>   (A) only I (B) only I and II (C) ... (D) ...  (E) ...
>
> Which of the following relations are ***odd***?
>
> I. something
>   II. something 
>   III. something
>
> **Results:**
>   (A) only I (B) only I and II (C) ... (D) ...  (E) ...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A (binary) relation $R \subseteq X \times Y$ is said to be **even**, if whenever $(x,y) \in R$ so is $(-x,y) \in R$. A binary relation is called **odd**, if whenever $(x,y) \in R$ so is $(-x,-y) \in R$.

Wasn't sure either at first, but the term is generalized from the usage in the study of functions (for a source see [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=s6vHpuq1U_gC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=even%20relation&source=bl&ots=peqMynLywR&sig=yj6nrvGcpxDgeIqIa9-TgwT6VRY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0sc-5iM_RAhWGVhQKHZ7pBvsQ6AEIKzAG#v=onepage&q=even%20relation&f=false)).

Comment: This was the first and most exhaustive response. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KaiWen You're welcome!